# Custom node migration for multi-value imagefield

Tags: 8, migrations, entities

I'm working on a custom migration module to "link" images to the imagefield.
It's work well for an unique value image field like this:

```
field_illus_vdl: 
  -
    plugin: d6_field_file
    source: field_illus_vdl
    migration: upgrade_d6_file
  -
    plugin: skip_on_empty
    method: process
```

But not for a multivalue imagefield after different tests:

```
field_galerie_image_vdl:
  -
    plugin: skip_on_empty
    method: process    
  -
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_galerie_image_vdl
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: d6_file (upgrade_d6_file doesn't change result)
        source: fid
      alt: alt
      title: title
      description: description
```

I try with `iterator` plugin, but no change.What is missing or wrong ? Do order is important between for chained processes ?

thanks

EDIT: I see [there](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-core-process-plugins) that `sub_process` replace `iterator` plugin.But I don't find infos about a `cckfield` plugin.

Devel data example:

```
field_galerie_image_vdl (Array, 6 elements)
0 (Array, 10 elements)
1 (Array, 10 elements)
fid (String, 4 characters ) 2006
uid (String, 1 characters ) 8
filename (String, 11 characters ) niger_3.jpg
filepath (String, 48 characters ) sites/all/media/galerie/actu/2018/20/niger_3.jpg
filemime (String, 10 characters ) image/jpeg
filesize (String, 6 characters ) 113504
status (String, 1 characters ) 1
timestamp (String, 10 characters ) 1526837277
list (String, 1 characters ) 1
data (Array, 3 elements)
description (String, 0 characters )
alt (String, 0 characters )
title (String, 0 characters )
```

Extract of a value for a filefield from var_dump:

```
[field_illus_vdl] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 2004
                [uid] => 8
                [filename] => niger4.jpg
                [filepath] => sites/all/media/illustration_vdl/2018/20/niger4.jpg
                [filemime] => image/jpeg
                [filesize] => 181770
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1526837126
                [list] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [alt] => Lycée Célony - Aix en provence
                        [title] => Lycée Célony
                    )

                [nid] => 471
                [view] => Lycée Célony - Aix en provence
            )

    )
```

This [source](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess) could be the right way,but I can't it work actually.

EDIT2: an format error in my YML file break the process, so after reorder the file, files are migrated.With a more simple code too:

```
 field_galerie_image_vdl:
  -
    plugin: d6_field_file
    source: field_galerie_image_vdl
    migration: upgrade_d6_file
  -
    plugin: skip_on_empty
    method: process
```

Comment: Can you give me a example about source fid?

Comment: Where can I find this ?

Comment: **soure: field_galerie_image_vdl** where do you provide this? You check in your migrate source.

Comment: ok, this is an imagefield migrated from D6, it's multi-value, 6 items max.In the D6 DB field, his name is field_galerie_image_vdl_fid

Comment: No, please don't misunderstand about field name and source provider. When you write **source: field_galerie_image_vdl** that mean **field_galerie_image_vdl** is value. In this case **field_galerie_image_vdl** must be an array number.

Comment: So in the DB, the field_galerie_image_vdl is in the content_node_field table, like field_illus_vdl , and contain same informations. But perhaps there is another place where data from the node are stored ?

Comment: I think I understand your ask. See EDIT to see data example from Devel.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from source migrate. When you using process **sub_process** source data must be an array like this:

```
[
    'fid' => 1,
    'another_key' => '...'
],
[
    'fid' => 2,
    'another_key' => '...'
],
[
    'fid' => 23,
    'another_key' => '...'
]
```

**Note: fid is old fid of database need to migrate.**

I'll show you a example migrate field image with multilple value. I have a content type with machine name **galary**. This content type have body and field images (machine_name: field_images) ullimited value.

[image]

I'll migrate data to this content. Create migration group **galary** with file name **migrate_plus.migration_group.galary.yml** and content

```
id: galary
label: Import galary images
description: Import field images has multilple values.
```

Create migration **file_images** with file name **migrate_plus.migration.file_images.yml**

```
id: file_images
label: 'Migrate images files'
migration_group: galary
source:
  constants:
    file_destination: 'public://galary/'
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    -
      fid: 1
      alt: 'Bootstrap'
      src: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/styles/grid-3/public/project-images/bootstrap_project_1.png'
      filename: 'bootstrap_project_1.png'
    -
      fid: 2
      alt: 'Adminimal - Responsive Administration Theme'
      src: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/adminimal-logo-slogan.png'
      filename: 'adminimal-logo-slogan.png'
    -
      fid: 3
      alt: 'AdaptiveTheme'
      src: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/styles/grid-3/public/project-images/Adaptivethemes_220.png'
      filename: 'Adaptivethemes_220.png'
    -
      fid: 4
      alt: 'Drupal8 Zymphonies Theme'
      src: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/styles/grid-3/public/project-images/desktop_8.png'
      filename: 'desktop_8.png'
  ids:
    fid:
      type: integer
process:
  public_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: ''
      source:
        - constants/file_destination
        - filename
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - src
      - '@public_path'
destination:
  plugin: entity:file
```

Create migration **node_images** with file name **migrate_plus.migration.node_images.yml** and content

```
id: node_images
label: Node galaryy
migration_group: galary
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    -
      nid: 1
      title: 'Bootstrap'
      body: 'Body Bootstrap'
      images: 1|3
    -
      nid: 2
      title: 'Adminimal - Responsive Administration Theme'
      body: 'Body Adminimal - Responsive Administration Theme'
      images: 2|4
  ids:
    nid:
      type: integer
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: galary
process:
  title: title
  'body/0/value': body
  'body/0/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: basic_html
  field_images:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: images
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: file_images
        source: fid
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - file_images
```

In my case, two source **file_images** and **node_images** I use the [embedded_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21EmbeddedDataSource.php/class/EmbeddedDataSource) source plugin for the sake of simplicity so that this example can be copy-pasted as a working example.

Let see **images: 2|4** or **images: 1|3** in data_rows.
I'll use **source: images** for process **sub_process** plugin but data is not like data example. So I need use [hook_migrate_prepare_row](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21migrate.api.php/function/hook_migrate_prepare_row/8.2.x) or method **prepareRow** in your source plugin to prepare soure.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_migrate_MIGRATION_ID_prepare_row().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_migrate_node_images_prepare_row(Row $row, MigrateSourceInterface $source, MigrationInterface $migration) {
  $images = $row->getSourceProperty('images');
  $images = explode('|', $images);
  $data = [];
  foreach ($images as $index => $fid) {
    $data[$index] = ['fid' => $fid];
  }
  $row->setSourceProperty('images', $data);
}
```

Now, you can import data to this content have multiple field images with

```
drush mim file_images && drush mim node_images
```